# Angular4をTomcat環境で動かしたい

Tags: angular4

Angular4をTomcat環境で動かそうとしていますが、
ルーティングで指定したURLにアクセスするとエラーになってしまします。

【手順】
@angular/cliを使用して、「ng new testApp」を実施して空のアプリを作成しました。
その後、URLをいくつか用意しました。
◇app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { Test2Component } from './test2.component';
import { Test3Component } from './test3.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/test', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component },
  { path: 'test3', component: Test3Component },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

ng serve --openコマンドを実施すると、以下のブラウザが開かれ画面が表示されます。
http://localhost:4200/test
その後、http://localhost:4200/test2、[http://localhost:4200/test3にアクセスすると](http://localhost:4200/test3%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8)
その画面が表示されました。

そこで、Tomcat環境に乗せてみようと思い、以下のコマンドでビルドを行いました。
ng build -prod

distフォルダが作成されたので、それらを以下に配置させてTomcatを実行してみました。
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\

それだけですとエラーとなってしまったのでdist配下のindex.htmlを以下に変更しています。

↓

すると、
[http://localhost:8080/distにアクセスすると](http://localhost:8080/dist%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8)、リダイレクトされ、
[http://localhost:8080/dist/testの画面が表示されることを確認できたのですが](http://localhost:8080/dist/test%E3%81%AE%E7%94%BB%E9%9D%A2%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C)、以下にアクセスすると、
HTTPステータス 404 - /dist/testエラーとなってしまいます。
http://localhost:8080/dist/test
http://localhost:8080/dist/test2
http://localhost:8080/dist/test3

何か設定などが必要なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これを追加しました。
    @NgModule({
     providers:[
       {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
      ]
    })

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001669/blank-page-except-index-html-with-angular-4-in-tomcat-environment
こちらを参考に以下のコマンドでビルドしました。
ng build --prod --aot=false --output-hashing=none --base-href=/dist/
その後、webappsへ配置してみると以下へのアクセスで画面表示が可能でした。
http://localhost:8080/sample/#/test
http://localhost:8080/sample/#/test2
http://localhost:8080/sample/#/test3

ただし、URLに「♯」が入ってしましました…。